# Displaying WMTS tiles over Google Map (iOS app) using capabilites XML as reference?

Tags: google-maps, arcgis-online, wmts

I have written an iOS app which can display a number of different layers on a Google Map. I am trying to add another layer which works fine on ArcGIS but I can't get it to work in my app.

There are no API keys or logins or anything required by the service.

Here is the [capabilities reference XML](https://gisbasemap.ecan.govt.nz/arcgis/rest/services/Imagery/Canterbury_Imagery_1990_1994/MapServer/WMTS).

Here it is working on ArcGIS Online:

[image]

[image]

Based on the information in the capabilities XML I have compiled this template URL:

```
https://gisbasemap.ecan.govt.nz/arcgis/rest/services/Imagery/Canterbury_Imagery_1990_1994/MapServer/WMTS/tile/1.0.0/Imagery_Canterbury_Imagery_1990_1994/default/default028mm/{z}/{x}/{y}
```

And here is a URL at a location and zoom that I would expect to return a tile:

```
https://gisbasemap.ecan.govt.nz/arcgis/rest/services/Imagery/Canterbury_Imagery_1990_1994/MapServer/WMTS/tile/1.0.0/Imagery_Canterbury_Imagery_1990_1994/default/default028mm/18/256785/166329
```

If I can get this to return a tile in a web browser I know I can get it to work in my app.

Have I misinterpreted the capabilities XML or is this something that is not possible in this case (ie. access only from ArcGIS Online)?

Answer (score 1):

By looking from the information of the map layer from here: https://gisbasemap.ecan.govt.nz/arcgis/rest/services/Imagery/Canterbury_Imagery_1990_1994/MapServer

You have stated the correct [WMS](https://gisbasemap.ecan.govt.nz/arcgis/services/Imagery/Canterbury_Imagery_1990_1994/MapServer/WMSServer?request=GetCapabilities&service=WMS)/[WMTS](https://gisbasemap.ecan.govt.nz/arcgis/rest/services/Imagery/Canterbury_Imagery_1990_1994/MapServer/WMTS/1.0.0/WMTSCapabilities.xml) Capabilities XML link.

You can use the image endpoint like this (as it is a common tileserver response from ArcGIS Map Server):
https://gisbasemap.ecan.govt.nz/arcgis/rest/services/Imagery/Canterbury_Imagery_1990_1994/MapServer/tile/{TileZoom}/{TileRow}/{TileCol}

For example: https://gisbasemap.ecan.govt.nz/arcgis/rest/services/Imagery/Canterbury_Imagery_1990_1994/MapServer/tile/12/1500/580

For your implementation (could be something like this) using Google Maps SDK iOS (I am not an iOS/Android Developer), as I referred it from [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/tiles#use_gmsurltilelayer_to_fetch_tiles_from_urls):

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
let urls = { (x: UInt, y: UInt, zoom: UInt) -> NSURL in
    let url = "https://gisbasemap.ecan.govt.nz/arcgis/rest/services/Imagery/Canterbury_Imagery_1990_1994/MapServer/tile\(zoom)/\(x)/\(y)"
    print(url)
    return NSURL(string: url)!
}
```

Comment: I haven't cracked this yet. Tried your template URL above. Could it be an issue with reference systems (EPSG:2193 in the capabilities doc vs EPSG:4326 expected by Google)?

Comment: You might need to convert to a suitable projection.